# Rails association works in the console but not in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

to-many association  between 2 modles. It works perfectly in the console but in the view just I get object-references appears like this:

```
#<Author:0x0000000434bf80>
#<Author:0x000000043485b0>
```

This appears in my view which has this code:

```
<h1 class="page-title">Articles</h1>
<hr>

<div class="category-container">
    <ul  class="category-titles">
      <% @cat.each do |c| %> 
       <li><%= link_to c.catName, category_path(c) %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<br><br><br><hr>

<% @art.each do |t| %>
 <p class="articles-list-page"><%= link_to t.artTitle, article_path(t)  %></p>
 <p><%= t.author %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my association in Author Model

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :articles
end
```

and Here is my association in Article Model

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :author
 end
```

**I could not understand why it is working well in the console but not in the view**

Comment: Sorry /i should also provide Controller Code. Please check this screenshot    http://imgur.com/zcsrEDk

Comment: has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 4):

It works fine in the view.

This line:

```
<p><%= t.author %></p>
```

outputs the author model. What you probably want to do is output the author name - something like

```
<p><%= t.author.name %></p>
```

Comment: I does not give an error but it shows object-reference like this (#<Author:0x0000000434bf80>). I want you to see the controller code in this screenshot http://imgur.com/zcsrEDk

Comment: When I put <%= t.author.name %> it gives an error as you see http://imgur.com/hb7M6iM and by the way, the field name of the author is authName

Comment: That means that `t` (the article) does not have a related `Author` object. According to your controller, `@art` contains all of your `Article` records, so at least one of those records has no associated Author.

Comment: Just use a conditional statement: `<%= t.author.authName if t.author %>`

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to output an ActiveRecord relation to the view. There's probably no situation ever where you'd want to display an entire ActiveRecord object in a view. Instead, you'd want to display particular *attributes* of the object.

Such as:

```
t.author.created_at
t.author.name
t.author.whatever
```

However, *if* there was some strange reason you wanted to output the entire object to the view, you could use `inspect` like so:

```
t.author.inspect
```

#### UPDATE:

To answer the other issue you're running into, you'll need to make sure that you actually *have* a related `Author` for each of the `Articles` before trying to output an Author attribute to the view. You can accomplish that like so:

```
<% if t.author.present? %>
  <p><%= t.author.authName %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>No author available</p>
<% end %>
```

Or like so, if you want to use a terniary operator to keep things on one line:

```
<p><%= t.author.present? ? t.author.authName : 'No author available' %></p>
```

Or if you don't care about returning a default value such as "No author available" if an `author` isn't available, then you could just do something like this:

```
<p><%= t.author.try(:authName) %></p>
```

Comment: But I got an error when I put author.authName and I am sure the field name is correct in the DB http://imgur.com/hb7M6iM

Comment: @steve check out my comment on the other answer about not having an associated Author.

Comment: @steve and I just updated my answer to address that issue you're having.

Comment: thank you. You gave me the solution. One article had (nil) author ID and I have associated an author ID to it. So now everything is working in the view.

Comment: Awesome! Glad everything's working for you now. If my answer worked for you, accepting and upvoting it would be good.

Comment: Also, even though you've got your data fixed now, I'd still *highly* recommend accounting for potential `nil` values in your view as well. I just added another option for handling nil values to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate that author attributes to `Article` model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :author
  delegates :authName, allow_nil: true
end
```

Also in your controller use following code

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @art = Article.includes(:author).all
  end
end
```

And in your view use like bellow

```
<% @art.each do |t| %>
 <p class="articles-list-page"><%= link_to t.artTitle, article_path(t)  %></p>
 <p><%= t.authName %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what does [ includes(:author) ] means ? When we need to use it ?

Comment: @steve the purpose of `includes(:author)` is for the sake of SQL efficiency. Essentially, if you know that you're going to reference a relationship of some model you're querying (in your case, referencing an `Author` from an `Article`), you can do `includes` with a parameter of whatever model (or models) you'll be referencing, and those relationships will go ahead and be loaded into memory. So when you reference them later, you don't have to fire an additional SQL query for each reference.